# main.css does not take effect even after loading in laravel

Tags: laravel-6

my webpage was working nicely the other day but today my main.css does not take any effect even after loading.

here is my **home.blade.php**

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/material-dashboard.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 @include("templates.partials.alerts")

 @yield('content')

</div><!-- end of div container -->
```

i can't find the error. what could be the cause of css not taking effect.
the other `<links ...>` are working nicely only main.css

Answer (score 0):

seems I had to vagrant provision twice